# Philips Hue App - out of home control sign-in problem

Tags: philips-hue, android

I am trying to control lights from outside using Hue app on my Android phone, but when I try logging in, by hitting 'log in' button under 'out of home control' under Settings, it takes me to an webpage api.meethue.com and display this:

> {"fault":{"faultstring":"Consumer Key not approved",
>       "detail":{"errorcode":"keymanagement.service.invalid_client-client_id_not_approved"}}  }

Did anyone have the same issue?

The app works fine when I am at home using wifi.

Answer (score 5):

Probably an old Android version on the phone. You need Android version 7.0 or higher. With Philips Hue app version 3.30 or higher. 3.30 is automatically installed by Google Play depending on the Android version on the phone.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Download the .apk from the internet and install it.

https://philips-hue.apk.gold/android-6.0

That should solve your issue.